# Parsing VCalendar

Tags: java, web-services, vcalendar, ical4j

I have an VCalendar retrieved by an url:

```
PRODID: test_online
VERSION: 1.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY: It's a test
DESCRIPTION: Test an vcalendar parser
LOCATION:
DTSTART: 11/6/2011 3:00:00 PM
DTEND: 11/10/2011 11:59:00 PM
CATEGORIES: Other tests
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Exists other way to parse such an vcalendar beside to split a string ? I have tried with Ical4j, but i got always the following error:

```
The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a    response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
```

My code is:

```
StringReader s = new StringReader(vcal);
CalendarBuilder builder = new CalendarBuilder();
Calendar c = builder.build(s);
System.out.println(c.toString());
```

Can anyone help me out ?

Best regards and thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately iCal4j only support iCalendar (i.e. VERSION:2.0), not vCalendar.

So for example, the dates in your example above don't conform to the iCalendar standard so it won't parse.

Answer (score 0):

Would the android VCal class help?

It has a string parser.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/CalendarProvider/+/donut-release2/src/com/android/providers/calendar/VCal.java